# How to retrieve multiple different files form firebase to flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I don't want to upload my code but I am having problems with retrieving multiple files from firebase storage. So in my app, I want to make users upload different files and while uploading it will show up in a list form.

The thing is I am able to save files into the firebase storage but I am freaking out trying to retrieve them into my application. I really hope if I get some to help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know what you're trying to achieve but maybe this would help.

When you upload your file to firestore storage, get a download link of that file and store it in the collection. Then you can retrieve the list of files you have uploaded.

1. Get the download URL of the uploaded file

```
 UploadTask imageUploadTask = storageReference.putFile(file);
    await imageUploadTask.whenComplete(() async {
      mediaURL = await imageUploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      print("download url = $mediaURL");
      return mediaURL;
    }).catchError((err){
      print(err.toString());
    });
```

2. Save URL to the collection

```
final CollectionReference _filesCollectionReference = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("files");
 Map<String, String> file = {
      "downloadURL" : url,
    };
    var result = await _filesCollectionReference.add(file);
```

3. Retrieve files
   await _filesCollectionReference.get();

Comment: hye! thanks for reaching out. I don't understand that like I have my one image file uploaded in Firebase storage. so I have to get the URL of this image file. now, how can I get all the files when i am reteriving only the image file while writng its url in the downlaod url thing.

Comment: This depends on the structure what you are trying to achieve. Eg. If you want to store image for a particular user then save the key,value pair along with the download url. When you want to retrieve image add a query where user id = "YOUR_USER_ID"